# Converting a .wav file to mono (delete right channel)

Tags: c, wav

[image]I'm trying to delete the right channel from a .wav file but to no avail. Some information about the original header:

NumChannels : 2, BlockAlign : 4, BitsPerSample : 16

From this I get that the sample size is 4 bytes(2Left + 2Right) so I'm creating a new file, writing the original header to it and then writing 4 bytes at a time to the new file from the original file with an AND mask 0xffff0000 to zero the right channel. Although it does seem like the volume from the right channel is decreased by 90%, I'm looking for some improvements. Parts of Code below:

```
int convertToMono(char *original) {
    Header *header = malloc(sizeof(Header));
    getHeader(header, original);

    FILE *fp = fopen(original, "rb");
    fseek(fp, HEADER_SIZE, 0);// Advance HEADER_SIZE bytes to data section

    // Create new file name
    char *name = malloc((5 + strlen(original)) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(name, "new-");
    strcat(name, original);

    // Open new file and write the header to it
    FILE *new = fopen(name, "wb");
    fwrite(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, new);

    u_int sample = 0;// unsigned int, size in bytes == 4
    for (int i = 0; i < header->chunkSize - HEADER_SIZE + 8; i += sizeof(u_int)) {
        fread(&sample, sizeof(u_int), 1, fp);
        sample = (sample & 0xffff0000);
        fwrite(&sample, sizeof(u_int), 1, new);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(new);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Added a picture from audio as displayed by Audacity.

Comment: Is `HEADER_SIZE` some constant?  If I recall, WAV files follow the RIFF format, meaning they can contain arbitrary data of variable length.  How are you certain that your function is landing on the beginning of the audio data?  How are you determining that the right channel is decreased by 90%?  Are you loading the waveform in an audio application and examining it?  If it's truly non-zero, then you are likely bleeding bits from the left channel through, suggesting that your alignment is off.

Comment: HEADER_SIZE is always 44 and the file format should be the header followed by the actual data. About the rest, I'm just playing the created file through the Groove music application on windows. Probably the audio driver tries to be smart and plays mono signals through both speakers.

Comment: It's not a mono signal.  It's a stereo signal with no audio on one channel.  This was one of my suspicions: that you might just be playing it in some app that is either mixing the audio, or your audio driver is running through some panning/blending, or some "surround" or reverb effect.  If you want to actually examine the WAV file, open it in a program like Audacity.

Comment: Audacity is showing no activity on the right channel but I can still hear it. Do you know of a way to convert to an actual mono signal? Maybe by changing some header data and parsing the original data to the new file differently? I might be already doing the correct steps but the headphones just mess up.

Comment: Try amplifying the waveform by about 30 dB and zoom in to see if there is any data there at all.  Probably there isn't.  Like I said, one thing to look at is whether your audio driver is doing some processing before output (check your playback device's properties in the System Sounds dialog - ensure all enhancements, sound effects, spatial sound etc are disabled).  It could also be your speakers / headphones either biasing the audio balance, mixing, faulty wires or connection, or even analog cross-talk (this one's a bit far-fetched).  At this point, your question probably isn't about coding.

Comment: Regarding conversion to true mono: yes, you change the channel count to 1 and write out only the left channel.  Or for proper mono conversion, you might mix the left and right together.  You probably also need to adjust the chunk size for the audio data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to mono, first you have to change the header information that are associated with the field numChannels:

```
header->numChannels = 1;
header->subchunk2Size /= 2;
header->chunkSize = header->subchunk2Size + 36;
header->byteRate /= 2;
header->blockAlign /= 2;
```

Then you open the new file and write the modified header to it:

```
FILE *fp2 = fopen("new.wav", "wb");
fwrite(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, fp2);
```

Create a buffer that can hold sample halves:

```
size_t channel_size = (size_t) (header->bitsPerSample / 8);
char sample[channel_size];
```

Read and write the left channel and ignore the right channel for all the samples.

```
for (int i = 0; i < header->subchunk2Size; i += channel_size) {
    fread(sample, channel_size, 1, fp1);
    fwrite(sample, channel_size, 1, fp2);

    fread(sample, channel_size, 1, fp1);
}
```

This will create a file that is half of the original in size and only the left channel will be heard. Note: This does not mean that the sound will only come from the left earphone.